# MVC show data based on current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, user-controls

I have a table in MVC with many to many relationship, inside the table is {**SubjectID,UserID,LevelID}** now how to filter the result of the table i want the current user is logged in can only see the  the **SubjectID,LevelId** that belongs to the current User. Any Simple Idea to make this Work? Thanks and Appreciate your response..

**Controller:**

```
    [Authorize(Roles ="Teacher")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var subjectTeachers = db.SubjectTeachers.Include(s => s.Levels).Include(s => s.Subjects).Include(s => s.Users);
        return View(subjectTeachers.ToList());
    }
```

**Model:**

```
 [Key]
    public int SubTech { get; set; }

    public int SubjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subjects { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User Users { get; set; }


    public int LevelID { get; set; }
    public virtual Level Levels { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Identity (with `AspNetUsers` table)? You can use something like `var subjectTeachers = db.SubjectTeachers.Where(x => x.Users.Any(n => n.UserID == user_id)).ToList()`.

Comment: No, i am using Empty template i only have Authentication and roles

Comment: Should i need to apply Identity? in order for me to get this done?

Comment: No, you don't need to use Identity, but you may try query like above.

Comment: should i need to remove my Index Code? and replace with this code? or just add this?

Comment: i mean Controller Index .

Comment: No, just change `var subjectTeachers` declaration into mentioned query above (if you getting error try examples from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097992/linq-to-entities-many-to-many-select-query).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use ASP.NET Identity, you can try replacing your line by:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Teacher")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var subjectTeachers = db.SubjectTeachers.Include(s => s.Levels).Include(s => s.Subjects).Include(s => s.Users).Where(u => u.UserID == id);
    return View(subjectTeachers.ToList());
}
```

You should pass the UserID from either session or through the controller and it should work.

Comment: What is the proper way here bro, should i need to add the Identity or not?

Comment: Its not about a proper way, if you want to implement Identity or not depends on you as adding Identity changes a lot of things. I would suggest not changing it now. So you can access like this. Try it once and tell me.

Comment: Bro. the code work in  reverse way meaning i teacher 1 can see the other teacher data but in his own data teacher1 cannot see